# Does supplying an ancestor improve filter queries performance in objectify / google cloud datastore?

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints, objectify, google-cloud-datastore

I was wondering which of these two is superior in terms of performance (and perhaps cost?):

1) `ofy().load().type(A.class).ancestor(parentKey).filter("foo", bar).list()`

2) `ofy().load().type(A.class)                    .filter("foo", bar).list()`

Logically, I would assume (1) will perform better as it restricts the domain on which to perform the filtering (though obviously there's an index). However, I was wondering if I may be missing some consideration/factor.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Including an ancestor should not significantly affect query performance (and as you note, each option requires a different index).

The more important consideration when deciding to use ancestor queries is whether you require strongly consistent query results. If you do, you'll need to group your entities into entity groups and use an ancestor query (#1 in your example).

The trade-off of grouping entities into entity groups is that each entity group only supports 1 write per second.

You can find a more detailed discussion of structuring data for strong consistency here: https://developers.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/structuring_for_strong_consistency

Comment: I'm encountering a bizarre situation so I want to make sure I understand this.
It seems that if I save() an entity which has a @Parent without using .now(), and then immediately load it using the type(tpe).parent(parentKey).id(id) I may not see the save.
This is confusing to me because I thought it is only in queries that we have to supply .ancestor to take advantage of strong consistency. On the loading side, the fact I'm including parent should do the same, should it not?

Comment: To give a bit more background: I encountered transient failures in some unit tests I wrote for my backend, and after a lot of tracing with the debugger, it _appears_ the issue is that I do not have now() when storing, which I thought was unnecessary if I'm saving/lading an entity with @Parent.

Comment: "Remember, if you do a lookup, an ancestor query, or any operation within a transaction, you will always see the most recently written data" The sentence is a bit ambiguous. Are they implying I need to be doing the lookup within a transaction OR that clause to the "any operation" part only? Ugh...

Comment: I'm not completely familiar with Objectify, but I think the save() option is asynchronous by default, which is why you may be seeing the old version on lookup. Calling now() forces the save to complete first. In general, Datastore's lookup-by-key operations will always return the latest version; there's no need to use a parent key (that's only required on queries).

Comment: Thanks Ed, what you are saying makes sense. Seems i do need to include .parent otherwise it cannot find the entity. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: That's right, if you originally saved the entity with a parent key, then you'll also need to use it to do the lookup. Glad I was able to help.